# Wrong HTML applying for Messages

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

We are using Magento's built in messaging system to show some messages to the user. However its not appearing properly in the front-end. When i checked the html using the firbug its appearing as follows:

```
<ul id="admin_messages">Please upload a CSV file with required details!</ul>
```

I'm using following code to add messages,

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Please upload a CSV file with required details!'));
```

Its only happening in one page and in rest of the pages the message appears properly. What might be the possible reasons for this issue. Can any one help me?

Comment: Can you share the URL to check?

Comment: Unfortunately  that page requires login credentials, which i'm not authorized to share. I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: You can share by creating a temporary user and allowing restricted area permission to that user.

Comment: @nikhil: are you using default magento theme OR rwd OR any custom theme ?

Comment: We are using a custom theme

Comment: ok, you are talking about front-end, right ? But here, if you check `<ul id="admin_messages">`, here id is `admin_messages`, doesn't it looks odd (something related to admin) ? Can you check for other pages ? is it same there also ?

Comment: Yes really strange... On other pages messages appear in correct format. Is it something to do with layout xml?